# A/B Test a Page Step in a Single Page without a new URL

Tags: extjs4.2, ab-testing, abtest

I am trying to figure out how to run an A/B Test for a change on a Page Step for a Single Page. The idea is we have a payment flow with several page steps each containing a form. We'd like to swap out forms and test how our users react. We are trying to avoid changing the URL.

I looked into tools such as Google Analytics, but that requires a different URL to run the A/B test. The hesitation about creating a new URL is because our users are known to bookmark them, and we don't want to keep a backlog of redirects from invalid URLs, also we'd like to avoid constantly deploying new URLs for our tests.

I cannot seem to find any tool to do this, so I've tried to think of a few solutions but I'm not having a lot of luck.

My best idea is to build both a and b forms into the page, and when a user accesses the flow, the session randomly(based on a preset%) stores a value that dictates whether the user is in test a or b. Then when they step into that form, the server will serve the proper form to them. If they abandon their session, we'd track that, and if they complete the action, we'd track that.

I feel like there should be a better solution, but I just cannot come up with one.

My results online were either blogs showing how to approach it from a high level, and all of them used different URLs, I have found almost no developer resources.

Thanks.

We're using ExtJS 4.2.2, and .NET as our server.

Comment: I think your solution is better than changing the url actually. Setting a cookie or a session parameter to decide which version a user will receive it's a good solution, in my view.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you need the server to be involved, you need server-side instrumentation. No free tools offer that, but you could consider Optimizely "full-stack" (has support for C#) or Variant (does not yet).